# Quick way to convert string to date in python

Tags: python

Is there a quick way to convert a string to a datetime object in Python WITHOUT having to specify the format?

I know I can do:

```
datetime.strptime('Sun 10 May 2015 13:54:36 -0700', '%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
```

But since this is the default format, is there someway to get it to autoparse? Seems like I should be able to just create a new object from this without having to specify the format since it is the default system format.

Comment: @mypetlion my question is that since the string is in the default format is there a quick way. That question is different format.

Comment: `datetime.datetime.strptime` is the function used by the top answer in that question and it allows you to specify a format. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) for a guide on how to specify a format.

Comment: @mypetlion you are missing the entire point of the question... I'm well aware of strptime. Edited the question so hopefully it is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

use `parser.parse` method from [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) module. You can install it by doing `pip install python-dateutil`

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse('Sun 10 May 2015 13:54:36 -0700')
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 10, 13, 54, 36, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -25200))
```